# Difference between ?? , has_content , if_exists in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

what is the difference between the following in freemarker?

```
!
has_content
?? 
if_exists
```

I used ?? instead of has_content & it lead to such huge issues. Screwed up my day. I really need to get this thing clarified.

When I used

```
!(xyz.abc!)?? -- it dint work
```

When I used

```
!(xyz.abc!)?has_content ... it did work
```

Doesn't ?? OR has_content OR if_exists check for the same thing?

Comment: see doc http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html

Answer (score 205):

[`??`](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test) tells if the left hand operand's value is missing (means it's Java `null` or you have an undefined variable there), and gives back `false` (missing) or `true` (not missing) accordingly.

[`?has_content`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_has_content) is very much like `??`, except it also returns `false` for a 0-length string or empty FTL sequence (like `java.util.List`, Java array, etc.) or empty FTL hash (like `java.util.Map`, etc.). (It doesn't return `false` for a `0`, boolean `false`, etc.)

[`!`](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default) is used to give a default value when a value is missing (again means that it's Java `null` or you have an undefined variable), like `color!"no color"`. If you omit the right hand operand of `!`, then the default value is an empty string and empty sequence and empty hash on the same time (a multi-typed value), which is handy for writing things like `<#list things! as thing>`, `${foo!}`.

[`?if_exists`](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing) is the old way of writing `??`. Don't use it.

While we are here, note that all these operators only cover the last step of a dotted or `[]` expression, like `user.price!0` only handles if `price` is missing from `user`, but not if `user` itself is missing. To cover both possibilities, use `(user.price)!0`, which handles all missing variable errors thrown during the evaluation of the `()`, no mater where they come from.

Comment: "well documented" statement deserves some links :)  
[has_content](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_has_content), [default value operator !](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default), [missing value test??](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_test), and [old style if_exists](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing)

Comment: `?has_content` is alwarys useful,except value is `Boolean` or `Number 1/0 for yes/no`

Comment: if this buyer not there in `<#elseif buyer.company?has_content >` it gives excception undefined how to check if buyer existst i tried all above !

Comment: @shareef If only `buyer` can be missing, but if it's there then ``company`` is always there, then `<#elseif buyer??>`, otherwise `<#elseif (buyer.company)??>` or `<#elseif (buyer.company)?has_content>`. The `()` makes the existence handler operators to cover the whole expression.