# How can I check null and empty both in freemarker string?

Tags: freemarker

For example.
String s can have these values like "value", "" or null.

```
<#if str?? && str?has_content>
    ${str}
</#if>
```

Can I check ??(null) and ?has_content(empty not null) both value in freemarker if statement not using TemplateModel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between ?? , has\_content , if\_exists in freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552151/difference-between-has-content-if-exists-in-freemarker)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`str?has_content` returns `true` if `str` is non-`null` (non-missing), and is also not a 0-length string. So you just need `<#if str?has_content>`.

(As of `TemplateModel`-s, every value is a `TemplateModel` as far as templates see. There's no such thing as a non-`TemplateModel` value.)